# Обращение к родительскому элементу CSS

Tags: html, css

Допустим у нас есть следующая структура:

```
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child></div>
</div>
```

Каким образом через CSS можно обратиться к родителькому блоку?
Например при событии `:hover` на `.child`, менялся фон у родительского блока `.parent`. И вообще возможно ли это?

Comment: Тоже задавался этим вопросом и пришел к тому, что нет. Можно реализовать на js

Comment: Можно наоборот обратиться от родителя к дочернему: `.parent { height: 500px; width: 200px; margin: 0 auto; border: 2px solid; } .child { margin-top: 100px; height: 80px; width: 80px; } .parent:hover .child { background-color: red; }`

Answer (score 7):

Разве, что так (способа, чтобы влиять на `parent` через `child` в `css` отсутствует)

```css
.parent{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.child{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;    
    background: #ccc;
}
.child:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: tomato;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transition: opacity .3s;
}
.child:hover:before{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
parent
   <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Здесь нет обращения в родителю через чайлда. А просто костыль.

Comment: @Sergey Novikov - способа, чтобы влиять на parent через child в css нет

Comment: я выше это и написал. Он написал _Например_ меняется фон, так что ваш костыль подходит только для этого.

Comment: @Sergey Novikov я и написал данный костыль исходя из условия вопроса

Comment: Думаю, в вопросе все же нужно было универсальное решение (если бы оно было), а пример с фоном - лишь для уточнения

Comment: Спасибо большое. Обидно, что сам до этого не додумался))

Comment: @Cheg - универсального решения на css увы нет, для данной задачи необходимо использовать javascript

Comment: @Lestalab, надо бы принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю способа сделать это через `CSS`, но вот удобный вариант через `JQuery`. Там можно использовать `parent()`:

```
$(".child").hover(
  function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass("green")
  },
  function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass("green")
  }
);
```

Comment: о jquery речи не было

Answer (score 0):

Это вроде только планируется реализовать в CSS4. А в CSS3 такой возможности нет.

Answer (score -1):

**В CSS3, через потомка, к родительскому элементу, обратиться невозможно.**

И да...

```css
.hello > .world {
  top: 0;
}
```

[image: обращение, через потомка, к родительскому элементу в CSS]

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, но только не совсем так как вы этого ожидали. В современном CSS есть псевдо класс [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:has), при его помощи можно решить вашу задачу. Сам `:has()` проверяет, имеет ли тот или иной селектор, совпадающий селектор записываемый в `:has()`, если имеет, только самому элементу применяются стили. Пример:

```css
header:has(h1) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

В данном примере идёт такая проверка: если у элемента, совпадающего с селектором `header`, имеется ребёнок (элемент) совпадающий с селектором `h1`, то тогда к элементу совпадающего с `header`, применяем красный фон. (Проще говоря, если у `header` есть `h1`, применяем красный фон к `header`)

К сожалению `:has()` появился в браузерах довольно поздно и у него плохая (мягко говоря) [совместимость со старыми браузерами](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:has#%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), а на Firefox (с 103 версии) так и вообще нужно включать специальную опцию в конфигурации браузера (нужно зайти в `about:config`, в поиске написать `layout.css.has-selector.enabled` и переключить значение на `true`). В остальных браузерах ничего включать не нужно и всё работает из коробки (Если у вас конечно достаточно свежая версия).

Вот само решение:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  background-color: red;
}

.parent:has(.child:hover) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Если же вы хотите, проверять не все `.child` на `:hover`, а только дочерние, то соответственно пишите так:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;

  background-color: red;
}

.parent:has(> .child:hover) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```